# Check if iPhone can send texts w/ MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: iphone

I am building an app that takes advantage of 4.0 features like in-app messaging but I also want my app to work on all 3.x versions. How do I check if the device can use MFMessageComposeViewController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple advises to use the `NSClassFromString` function to determine if the class is available. Don't forgot to weak link against the message framework as mentioned before.

Example from the MessageComposer sample:

```
-(IBAction)showSMSPicker:(id)sender {
//  The MFMessageComposeViewController class is only available in iPhone OS 4.0 or later. 
//  So, we must verify the existence of the above class and log an error message for devices
//      running earlier versions of the iPhone OS. Set feedbackMsg if device doesn't support 
//      MFMessageComposeViewController API.
Class messageClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMessageComposeViewController"));

if (messageClass != nil) {          
    // Check whether the current device is configured for sending SMS messages
    if ([messageClass canSendText]) {
        [self displaySMSComposerSheet];
    }
    else {  
        feedbackMsg.hidden = NO;
        feedbackMsg.text = @"Device not configured to send SMS.";

    }
}
else {
    feedbackMsg.hidden = NO;
    feedbackMsg.text = @"Device not configured to send SMS.";
}
}
```

Link: [MessageComposer sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MessageComposer/Listings/Classes_MessageComposerViewController_m.html)

**Update:** The sample code I posted checks for the availability of the SMS composer, checking for the mail composer is similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

if ( dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "MFMailComposeErrorDomain") != NULL ) {
        // MFMessageComposeViewController framework is available
} else {
        // do alternative for no MFMessageComposeViewController
}
```

Don't forget to weak link the MFMessageUI framework.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the device's current operating system using the `UIDevice` class.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html

The `systemName` and `systemVersion` properties may be what you're looking for.  You'll also need to weak link the framework!